# change jquery to javascript simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery

**sorry guys, asked a bit wrongly, here is the EDIT**

got a simple question, how to change the this jquery code to a javascript:

```
$("#gotoPage").click(function(){
        var abr = $("#txtPageNumber").val();
        paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);
    });
```

and this inputs:

```
<div class="gotoPage_div">
                <input type="text" id="txtPageNumber" class="txtPageNumber" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');check(this);" value="<cfoutput>#attributes.page#</cfoutput>" />
                <span>Lütfen, sayfa numarası giriniz <cfoutput>1-#lastpage#</cfoutput></span>
            </div>
            <div class="gotoSubmit">
                <input type="submit" id="gotoPage" class="gotoPage" value="Değistir" style="width:50px;" />
            </div>
```

to smth like this:

```
function change_page {
        var abr = document.getElementById('txtPageNumber').value;
        document.change_page.action=paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);
    }
```

and i created a form and i want to change its action:

```
<form method="post" name="change_page" action="change_page()">
            <div class="gotoPage_div">
                <input type="text" id="txtPageNumber" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''" class="txtPageNumber" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');check(this);" value="<cfoutput>#attributes.page#</cfoutput>" />
                <span>Lütfen, sayfa numarası giriniz <cfoutput>1-#lastpage#</cfoutput></span>
            </div>
            <div class="gotoSubmit">
                <input type="submit" id="gotoPage" class="gotoPage" value="Değistir" style="width:50px;" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var abr = document.getElementById('txtPageNumber').value;
paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
var abr = document.getElementById("txtPageNumber").value;
paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var abr = document.getElementById('txtPageNumber').innerHTML;
paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`override` the `onclick` event for the `element`.

```
document.getElementById('gotoPage').onclick = function(){
var abr = document.getElementById('txtPageNumber').value;
paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1', abr);    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#gotoPage").click(function(){
        var abr = $("#txtPageNumber").val();
        paging_go_page_('cf_pages_form_name1',abr);
    });
```

Without jQuery will be:

```
document.getElementById( 'gotoPage' ) // = > $("#gotoPage")
[ document.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent" ]  // now depends on browser type we choose proper method to bind event handler and invoke this 
( "click" , function() {   
    paging_go_page( 'cf_pages_form_name1', document.getElementById( "txtPageNumber" ).value);

  } , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you want to change form's action
document.change_page.action = "your action url here";
```

Comment: can it be there not the url but the function?

Comment: form action should be a url, to which page you will be posting your form